# How does Qt share OpenGL contexts behind the curtain?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am writing an application that:

- Continuously renders stuff offscreen in a pipeline that has private OpenGL context & private thread
- Draws some of the previously rendered textures in widgets

In order to do that I need to share those textures across both the pipeline and the widgets contexts:

**Approach 1 : share all contexts**

```cpp
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts);
     QApplication a(argc, argv);

     // [...] Create and initialize the pipeline (private context)
     // [...] Create a window with a widget that can display a texture (Qt creates a private context itself)
     // [...] Set the texture to display in the widget with one created and rendered in the pipeline
}
```

By the time i want to draw my texture (in the `paintGL()` callback), `glBindTexture` yields a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.
Graphics debugger shows a weird texture instead of mine : context sharing does not seem to work.

**Approach 2 : widget have a self created context that shares both the pipeline and the Qt one**

```cpp
// [...] Create and initialize the pipeline (private context)
// [...] Create a window with a widget that can display a texture (Qt creates a private context itself)
// widget's initializeGL() callback gets called
void initializeGL()
{
     initializeOpenGLFunctions();
     m_secondContext.setShareContext(QOpenGLContext::currentContext());
     m_secondContext.setShareContext(pipelineContext);
     m_secondContext.create();
}
// use the second context during paintEvents
void paintGL()
{
     auto contextBackup(QOpenGLContext::currentContext());
     auto surfaceBackup(contextBackup->surface());
     assert(m_secondContext->makeCurrent(surfaceBackup));

     // [...] draw texture

     contextBackup->makeCurrent(surfaceBackup);
}
```

Does not work either, yields same error as approach 1 + some more that i have not located.

**Approach 3 : Pipeline share the widgets context**

```cpp
// [...] Create a window with a widget that can display a texture (Qt creates a private context itself)
// [...] Create and initialize the pipeline with the widgets context set as shared 
//       before calling create on the new pipeline context
void initializePipeline()
{
     m_pipelineContext.setShareContext(widgetContext);
     m_pipelineContext.create();
}
```

This does work, BUT it is an unwanted solution as it does not allow the creation of such widgets AFTER the pipeline initialization

**Questions i am asking:**

- All theses three scenarios should give the same result, what is happening, what did i miss ?
- Does one need to add specific instructions to allocate shared resource on a context that is shared?
- Is context sharing thread safe ? E.g can i use shared resources without caring about mutual exclusion ? (edit: using one does not solve any issue)

Comment: Since it's working if using CodeXL: After rendering to the texture, do you run `glFlush` or `glFinish` to "commit" the context command queue? Because you should.

Comment: I was mistaken, it does not work on CodeXL (it executed another version of the program). glFlush does not solve the problem though

Answer (score 1):

Answering you questions:

> Does one need to add specific instructions to allocate shared resource
>   on a context that is shared?

No.

> Is context sharing thread safe ? E.g can i use shared resources
>   without caring about mutual exclusion?

Context sharing is not thread safe. Sharing is a consolidation of OpenGL object namespace.

But I suspect those answers do not help you at all. I'll keep going with an observation. Your error is strange because `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is only generated in one scenario for `glBindTexture`:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if *texture* was previously created
>   with a target that doesn't match that of *target*.

Which indicates there is a texture with the name `textureHandle`, just not with target `GL_TEXTURE_2D`. Perhaps the texture target is actually `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE`?

Of course there is the possibility that the sharing does not work for whatever reason. This should be easily found using just about any graphics debugger to list objects in each context; create in one, see if it pops up in the other.

Comment: Thanks :) I use Renderdoc but i cannot find how to list objects in a context. It seems to me that it is indeed a sharing problem because in the debugger, the displayed texture is some ASCII characters texture (weird), and the target is a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` at both creation and usage time. I added a mutex lock in all three `initializeGL() paintGL()` and `resizeGL()` just to be sure, yet the problem remains.

Comment: @AdrienGrosjean CodeXL is my preferred debugger for analyzing the GL state. Suggestion: Instead of using the global `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(...)`, try using `setShareContext()` before `create()` on the QOpenGLContext class instance.